# How to merge Schema With Rows when querying a full row from bigquery - java

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I uploaded the following record to biqQuery:

```
{
  insertId: "1234",
  executionId: "1111",
  jobs:[
    {name:"aaaa", version:"0.0.0"},
    {name:"bbbb", version:"0.0.0"},
    {name:"cccc", version:"0.0.0"},
  ]
}
```

here is my schema

```
[
  {"name":"insertId", "type":"STRING"},
  {"name": "executionId","type": "STRING"},
  {
    "name": "jobs",
    "type": "record",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "version",
        "type": "STRING"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I am querying in java

```
"SELECT * FROM `myDataset.myTable` where executionId=\"1111\" ;"
```

here is the code I am using taken from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/samples/SyncQuerySample.java):

```
    String projectId = "myProjectId";
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM `myDataset.myTable` where executionId=\"1111\" ;"; 
    long waitTime = 10000;
    boolean useLegacySql = false;

    Iterator<GetQueryResultsResponse> pages = run(projectId, queryString, waitTime, useLegacySql);
    List<TableRow> tableRow = pages.next().getRows();
    for(TableRow row: tableRow)
    {
        System.out.println(row);
    }
```

here is the output I get:

```
{
      "f": [
        {"v": "1234"},
        {"v": "1111" },
        {"v": [
          {"v": { "f": [
                  { "v": "aaaa" },
                  { "v": "0.0.0"}
                ]
              }
            },
            {"v": { "f": [
                  { "v": "bbbb"},
                  { "v": "0.0.0" }
                ]
              }
            },
            { "v": {
                "f": [
                  {"v": "cccc" },
                  {"v": "0.0.0"}
                ]
              }
            } ]}]}
```

now my schema is dynamic might contain nested and repeated fields, some are null, how can I merge schema with rows and get my original data dynamically according to the schema?

(something like `mergeSchemaWithRows(schema, rows)` there is in the [google-cloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/blob/vision-0.12.0/packages/bigquery/src/table.js#L261) npm package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what I did:

```
/**
     * Merge a rowset returned from the API with a table schema.
     *
     * @static
     * @private
     *
     * @param {object} schema
     * @param {array} rows
     * @return {array} Fields using their matching names from the table's schema.
     */
      public static JSONObject mergeRowsWithSchema(JSONArray schemaArr, JSONObject row) {

          JSONObject convertedJson = new JSONObject();
          JSONArray jsonFields = row.getJSONArray("f");
          int i = -1;
          for (Object field : jsonFields) {
              i++;
              JSONObject fieldObj = (JSONObject)field;
              if(fieldObj.isNull("v")) continue;
              Object value = fieldObj.get("v");
              JSONObject schemaField = schemaArr.getJSONObject(i);
              Object convertedValue = null;
              if (schemaField.has("mode") && schemaField.getString("mode").toUpperCase().equals("REPEATED")) {
                  JSONArray convertedArray = new JSONArray();
                  for (Object val : (JSONArray)value) 
                      convertedArray.put(convert(schemaField,((JSONObject)val).get("v")));
                  convertedValue = convertedArray; 

              }
              else
                  convertedValue = convert(schemaField, value);
              convertedJson.put(schemaField.getString("name"), convertedValue);
            }
          return convertedJson;

      }

    private static Object convert(JSONObject schemaField, Object value) {
        if(value == null || value.equals(null)) return value;
        switch (schemaField.getString("type").toUpperCase()) {
          case "STRING": 
              return value;
          case "BOOLEAN": 
                return value.equals("true");
        case "FLOAT": 
           return Float.parseFloat((String)value);
        case "INTEGER":
           return Integer.parseInt((String)value);
        case "RECORD":
              return mergeRowsWithSchema(schemaField.getJSONArray("fields"), (JSONObject)value); 
        case "TIMESTAMP":
              long lng =(long)Double.parseDouble((String)value);
                Date date = new Date(lng * 1000);
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
                return dateFormat.format(date);
      }
        return null;
    }
```